# Edit iCloud PDF file issue

Tags: ios, xamarin

I have PDF files in iCloud. and i need to edit them. I tried many ways but PDF always opening as copy in acrobat reader. is it possible to edit them without copy to local. Please give some ideas.

In here first i am uploading pdf of to icloud. after that i am openning it. i tried to open it to acrobat.but not openning it directly. a dialogue box will appear and ask to copy to acrobat.

```
 public void UploadiCloud(string filepath, string fileName)
    {

        UIDocumentPickerViewController documentPicker = new UIDocumentPickerViewController(NSUrl.FromFilename(filepath), UIDocumentPickerMode.ExportToService);
        documentPicker.DidPickDocumentAtUrls += (object sender, UIDocumentPickedAtUrlsEventArgs e) =>
        {

            NSUrl adobeUrl = new NSUrl($"com.adobe.adobe-reader://");
            NSUrl fileUrl = NSUrl.FromFilename(filepath);
            UIDocumentInteractionController docController = UIDocumentInteractionController.FromUrl(fileUrl);

            if (UIApplication.SharedApplication.CanOpenUrl(adobeUrl))
            {

                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    UIView presentingView = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.View;
                    docController.PresentOpenInMenu(CGRect.Empty, presentingView, true);

                });
            }
            else
            {

            }
        };
        documentPicker.ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.FormSheet;
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.PresentViewController(documentPicker, true, null);

    }
```

Comment: Could you add some code to this question that shows ***how*** you are attempting to edit these PDF files in Xamarin?

Comment: @Michael Dautermann I had updated my question with the code. pls check